# AJAX retorna a mesma resposta

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um formulário de login com PHP e JQUERY:

**index.php:**

```
   <form action="." method="POST" class="form-signin">
      <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Entrar</h1>
      <label for="name" class="sr-only">name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario...">
      <label for="word" class="sr-only">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="word" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha...">
      <button style="margin-top: 50px;" id="login" class="btn btn-style btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"><strong>Logar</strong></button>
      <div style="margin-top: 35px;">
      <div id="add_err" class="card">
      </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

**login.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_err").css('display', 'none', 'important');
     $("#login").click(function(){  
          username=$("#name").val();
          password=$("#word").val()
          $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "login.php",
           data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
           success: function(html){    
            if(html=='true')    {
             $("#add_err").html("right username or password");
             //window.location="../index.php";
            }
            else    {
            $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
            $("#add_err").html("<font style='margin-top: 50px; padding: 20px; background-color: #C70039; color: white; border-width: 0px;'>Usuario o Senha incorretos</font>");
            $("#login").html('<strong>Logar</strong>');
            }
           },
           beforeSend:function()
           {
            $("#login").html("<div class='spinner'><div class='bounce1'></div><div class='bounce2'></div><div class='bounce3'></div></div>");
            $("#add_err").css('display', 'none', 'important');
            $("#login").blur();
           }
          });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**login.php:**

```
    sleep(3);
    session_start(); 
        //Incluindo a conexão com banco de dados   
    include_once("../assets/php/config.php");    
        $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']); //Escapar de caracteres especiais, como aspas, prevenindo SQL injection
        $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pwd']);
        $senha = md5($senha);

        //Buscar na tabela usuario o usuário que corresponde com os dados digitado no formulário
        $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE name = '$usuario' && password = '$senha' LIMIT 1";
        $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($con, $result_usuario);
        $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);

        //Encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
        if(isset($resultado)){
            echo "true";
            $_SESSION['ID']             = $resultado['id'];
            $_SESSION['NAME']           = $resultado['name'];
            $_SESSION['PASSWORD']       = $resultado['password'];
            $_SESSION['LEVEL']          = $resultado['level'];
            }else{
                echo "false";
            }
```

O script faz a consulta no banco de dados e retorna, caso seja encontrado ele retorna `'true'` e exibe a mensagem de sucesso, se não encontrar ele retorna `'false'` e a mensagem de erro, o problema é que independente do resultado da consulta '`true'` ou `'false'` ele exibe a mensagem de erro!

Comment: E qual seria essa mensagem de erro? Será que essa mensagem não é na verdade uma mensagem de aviso (warning)? Porque se fosse uma mensagem de erro real, uma exceção não capturada, provavelmente seu código teria parado de executar antes mesmo de imprimir "false";

Comment: @user140828 A mensagem de erro é a que aparece quando o usuário ou a senha estão incorretos!

Comment: Sim, mas qual seria essa mensagem? Ela é gerada por você ou pelo PHP? O que está escrito nela? Esses pontos ajudam a descobrir a razão do erro, mas você não postou de onde vem essa mensagem, não tem como ajudar apenas sabendo que em algum lugar existe uma mensagem de erro que desconhecemos como é gerada e qual seu conteúdo.

Comment: @user140828 Ah, sim... Ela é gerado no javascript (login.js). no if e else (Usuario ou senha incorretos)! fiz o debug do script e consta que ele fez a consulta e teve o retorno, ou seja o codigo não ta parando antes

Comment: Faça um `console.log(html);` antes de `if(html=='true')    {` e poste aqui pra vermos...

Comment: @LipESprY usuario e senha corretos: console.log(HTML) = 'true'. Usuario e senha incorretos console.log(HTML) = 'false'. funcionando normalmente, creio que o problema esteja no AJAX mas não tô conseguindo encontrar!

Comment: Bro. Seu `if/else` estão funcionando. Reproduzi, em parte, o seu problema. Fiz uma página PHP com `echo 'true';` / `echo 'false';` e o AJAX funcionou perfeitamente. Até mesmo no `if/else`. Tem mais algum código aí que possa estar influenciando?

Comment: @LipESprY nenhum outro codigo! que versão do jquery vc usou ? vc pode postar seu codigo pra que eu possa testar ?

Comment: Posso sim! Mais tarde, se ainda não tiver solução aqui, posto pra vc. Estou no cel agora (longe do PC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>A pesar de não ter encontrado nenhum erro lógico no seu código:</strike>

> "*- vc pode postar seu codigo pra que eu possa testar ?*"

---

Como a responsabilidade do servidor é só responder `true` ou `false`, utilizei `admin/admin` a fim de testes. Nada te impede de utilizar seu próprio script.

**login.php:**

```
<?php
    //sleep(3);
    if (
        $_POST['name'] == 'admin'
        && $_POST['pwd'] == 'admin'
    )
        echo 'true';
    else
        echo 'false';
```

---

Na página HTML, não fiz nada além de **organizar**. Mas acho importante postar para que você confira os scripts do cabeçalho e facilite na sua reprodução. Pode até aproveitar o código, já que está mais organizado.

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login com AJAX</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="login.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form class="form-signin">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Entrar</h1>
            <label for="name" class="sr-only">Name</label>
            <input
                type="text"
                id="name"
                name="name"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Usuario...">
            <label for="word" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input
                type="password"
                id="word"
                name="password"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Senha...">
            <button
                style="margin-top: 50px;"
                id="login"
                class="btn btn-style btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
                <strong>Logar</strong>
            </button>
            <div style="margin-top: 35px;">
                <div id="add_err" class="card"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<!-- por LipESprY -->
```

---

Já no JavaScript, tive o prazer de **quase** inutilizar o jQuery na sua página. Só mantive a parte do *AJAX*, que é um dos poucos métodos dele que ainda recomendo utilizar.

Vale lembrar que mantive "praticamente toda" a estrutura e lógica do seu código. No final, deve obter visivelmente o mesmo resultado. Não vou entrar em muitos detalhes, o código está bem fácil de entender...

**login.js:**

```
document.addEventListener(
    'DOMContentLoaded',
    function(){

        let dvErro = document.getElementById('add_err');
        let btn = document.getElementById('login');

        btn.addEventListener(
            'click',
            function(ev){
                ev.preventDefault();

                let username = document.getElementById('name').value;
                let password = document.getElementById('word').value;

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'login.php',
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {
                        name: username,
                        pwd: password
                    },

                    beforeSend: function(){
                        dvErro.style.display = 'none';
                        btn.innerHTML = (
                            '<div class="spinner">'
                            +'<div class="bounce1"></div>'
                            +'<div class="bounce2"></div>'
                            +'<div class="bounce3"></div>'
                            //+'spinner' // Para reprodução
                            +'</div>'
                        );
                        btn.blur();
                    },

                    success: function(resposta){
                        dvErro.style.display = 'inline';

                        if (resposta == 'true') { // Login OK
                            dvErro.innerHTML = 'right username or password';
                            // Redireciona:
                            //window.location.href = 'index.php';
                        } else if (resposta == 'false') { // Login ERRO
                            dvErro.innerHTML = (
                                '<font style="'
                                +'margin-top: 50px; padding: 20px; '
                                +'background-color: #C70039; '
                                +'color: white; border-width: 0px;">'
                                +'Usuario ou Senha incorretos'
                                +'</font>'
                            );
                            btn.innerHTML = '<strong>Logar</strong>';
                        } else { // Notifica caso receba alguma outra resposta
                            console.log(resposta);
                            alert('Servidor retornou resposta inválida.');
                        }
                    },

                    error: function(erro){
                        console.log(erro);
                        alert('Erro no AJAX - detalhes no console.');
                    }
                });
            },
            false
        );
    },
    false
);
```

Obs.: não é má ideia atualizar para a versão 3.3.1 do jQuery, que é a mais recente da biblioteca. Tem pouca diferença na sintaxe do *AJAX*, mas nada difícil de implementar... Dê uma olhadinha na [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

---

Para finalizar, este é o resultado:

[image: demonstracao]

O material dessa resposta está disponível no meu [GitHub/lipespry](https://github.com/lipespry/lsi-sopt/tree/master/JavaScript/ajax-retorna-a-mesma-resposta%5B367346%5D).